# Present Modal showing black screen

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to present a Modal. When I hook it up to a button, it displays no problem.  [image][image]. But when I call it programmatically, it shows a black screen.

Here is how I'm calling it.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    presentViewController(ModalViewControllerClass(), animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I'm on swift 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try another way to programmatically present your destination ViewController. Try this code:

```
let sB: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) //name of your storyboard
let newVC: UIViewController = sB.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("<YourVC'sRestorationID>") //if you have the restoration ID, otherwise use 'ModalViewController'
newVC.modalTransitionStyle = .CrossDissolve //if you want it to have a special transition style
self.presentViewController(newVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You should set up a size of your ViewController's view. (In general it could be different, it does not have to be full screen.) StoryBoard does it for you during instantiation if you instantiate a view controller from UIStoryBoard. In your case you should do it yourself

```
let vc = ModalViewControllerClass()
vc.view.frame = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.bounds
presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply instantiating an instance of `ModalViewControllerClass` won't work.

You should use the storyboard function `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`

If you add the identifier "MyModal" to your modal's scene in your storyboard then your code might look like this:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) 
{
  if let newModal =   
    self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyModal")
  {
    presentViewController(newModal, animated: true, completion: nil);
  }
}
```

Comment: What's with the down-vote? What was wrong with my answer? Please explain.